# It asks something different, and it needs a different answer, so can we reopen it?

Tags: discussion, duplicates, closed-questions

**Edit**: question reopened. Thanks :)

---

[Can you have too much swap?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1017021/can-you-have-too-much-swap) is closed as a duplicate of [I have 16GB RAM. Do I need 32GB swap?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49109/i-have-16gb-ram-do-i-need-32gb-swap)

But the first question is asking what problems might arise from having too much swap. It takes for granted that *more swap is good* and asks whether and how the idea that more swap is good breaks down at some point.

By contrast, the second question and all its answers take for granted that *less swap is good* and swap should be kept to a necessary minimum. They explain why some swap may be needed and how much swap may be needed for various purposes. None of them attempt to consider the possible ill-effects of having *too much* swap, because they take for granted that swap is an inconvenience, a chunk of the disk you'd rather fill with cat pictures.

The first question already has answers that point out that you can't fill swap space with cat pictures (I'm paraphrasing slightly), but it deserves answers that explain other possible ill-effects which [do exist](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1017021/can-you-have-too-much-swap#comment1654597_1017021).

Please can we reopen this question?

Comment: Howµ about closing it as a duplicate of [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/594054/how-much-swap-should-i-take-for-1-128gb-ram-on-14-04-or-higher/594402#594402)?

Comment: I don't see how it is a duplicate of that much more specific question which doesn't ask the same thing...

Comment: Cool! Thanks!  **:-)**  I upvoted David's answer on the original as that is the only good one...  **;-)**

Comment: People be power tripping sometimes..... I could see the too much swap topic ending up in my hot list. It's a more interesting topic to me then do I need 32GB.